# 改行を挿入する形で置換しようとしたとき、最後に余計な改行が入る

Tags: sed, 正規表現

例えば `sample.txt`というファイルがあり、その中に下のような文章が書かれていたとします。

```
これは普通の質問だな。ただ、この質問は良い質問だ。でも、これは悪い質問だ。
```

このテキストファイルに対し、「。」毎に改行を入れたいと思ったとします。上の例でいうならば、下のようなことを意図しています。

```
これは普通の質問だな。
ただ、この質問は良い質問だ。
でも、これは悪い質問だ。
```

そこで、`sed "s/。/。\n/g" sample.txt`という形で改行を挿入するのを試みました。すると、結果としては最後の`。`でも改行が入ってしまい、空行が最後についてしまいます。

渡し先で空行を無視するようにもできますが、どうせならこの置換の時に、最後の空改行を防ぐ形にしたいと思うのですが、どのようにするのがベターでしょうか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

幾つかやり方はあると思いますが、
`。` のあとに任意の文字があることを利用した、
こんなやり方はどうでしょうか。

```
sed -e 's/。\(.\)/。\n\1/g' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU版の sed をお使いであれば、以下の様にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
$ sed -r 's/。/。\n/g;s/\n+$//' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

需要があるのかわかりませんが`mac`の`sed`では

```
sed -e 's/。\(.\)/。\'$'\n\\1/g' sample.txt
```

となります。

(ちょっと独自仕様なので、普通は`brew install gnu-sed`をして`gsed`を使うべきかと。。)

Answer (score 0):

> ＞ 空行が最後についてしまいます。

このようになる そもそもの原因は sample.txt が改行で終わっていることなのでは？

emacs で普通に 文書を作って、od で文末がどうなっているか調べてみました。

```
$ cat sample.txt | od -cx | tail -1
0000140   い  **  **  質  **  **  問  **  **  だ  **  **  。  **  **  \n
             81e3    e884    aab3    95e5    e38f    a081    80e3    0a82
0000160
```

最後に 改行がついていることがわかります。

この状態で "。” を "。\n" に変換すれば、ファイルの最後は "。\n\n" となります。

ファイルの最後が "。" や "。\n" のどちらの場合でも改行なしに "。" で終わらせるように変換するコマンド ruby のワンライナーで書いてみました。

```
$ cat sample.txt | ruby -e 'line=STDIN.gets; printf line.strip.gsub(/。/, "。\n").chomp'
```

これを実行すると次のようになります。(最後が改行されずに shell のコマンドプロンプトが表示されます)

```
$ cat sample.txt | ruby -e 'line=STDIN.gets; printf line.strip.gsub(/。/, "。\n").chomp'
これは普通の質問だな。
ただ、この質問は良い質問だ。
でも、これは悪い質問だ。$
```

Comment: ファイルの末尾に改行コードがない場合、diff コマンドで「No newline at end of file」と表示されたり、
--『$ diff sample.txt <(head -c -1 sample.txt) => ...\ No newline at end of file』--
wc コマンドでの出力結果が期待したものとは異なってしまったりします。--『$ head -c -1 sample.txt | wc -l => 0』--
これは UNIX tools の多くが「行単位」で処理を実行するので仕方がないのですが、基本的にファイルの末尾には改行コードを含めておいた方が良さそうです。

Answer (score 0):

純粋に「空行がでてしまう」ということに対して汎用的なアプローチをするなら

`sed "s/。/。\n/g" sample.txt | grep -v '^$'`

といった具合に空行を除去するという方法もあります。

ただし、変換したファイルに空行のみの行を許容する場合は、この方法ではその空行も除去されてしまうため、お気をつけ下さい。